# How to get data from multiple join on same table

Tags: oracle

I have the below tables . Here `trav_go_id` and `trav_ret_id` is related to the `trav_id` field in the travel table. There is no relation ship on the primary key `rese_id` or with the travel table

```sql
CREATE TABLE RESERVATION (
  RESE_ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, TRAV_GO_ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, TRAV_RET_ID NUMBER(10, 0) ---this is nullable column
);
    
CREATE TABLE TRAVEL (
  TRAV_ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL   -- The value in this will be either the TRAV_GO_ID or 
, DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME DATE 
, ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME DATE 
) 

insert into RESERVATION(RESE_ID,TRAV_GO_ID,TRAV_RET_ID) values ( 1, 222, 555);
insert into RESERVATION(RESE_ID,TRAV_GO_ID,TRAV_RET_ID) values ( 2, 333, null);
insert into RESERVATION(RESE_ID,TRAV_GO_ID,TRAV_RET_ID) values ( 3, 444, null);

insert into TRAVEL(TRAV_ID,DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME,ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME) values 
( 222, (TO_DATE('2024/08/29 01:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')), (TO_DATE('2024/08/29 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')));
    
insert into TRAVEL(TRAV_ID,DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME,ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME) values 
( 444, (TO_DATE('2024/08/27 01:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')), (TO_DATE('2024/08/27 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')));

insert into TRAVEL(TRAV_ID,DEPARTURE_DATE_TIME,ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME) values 
( 333, (TO_DATE('2024/08/29 01:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')),null);
```

I want to select all the details from both the tables where travel tables `departure_date_time > todaysdate`

here if current date is 28/08/2024 the i need to get only the reservation with travel tables departure time > 28/08/2024. that is the first record with id 1,2

```
select count(*) from RESERVATION r inner  join travel t on r.trav_go_id = t.trav_id
inner  join travel tt on r.trav_ret_id = tt.trav_id
```

Here is what I have tried, but it ignores the reservations with `ret_id` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
select count(*)
from   RESERVATION r
       inner join travel go
       on r.trav_go_id = go.trav_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN travel ret
       on r.trav_ret_id = ret.trav_id
```

Which outputs:

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A_SV2Ivy)